# Reducing impact of SUM(DATALENGTH()) over linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a query that reports back to me how much time elapsed for records to be added. I also in this query track the size of an image that was added to the database. From what I can see it looks like it is returning the whole image from the linked server and then calculating the size. Is there an easy way I can get the calculation of size to occur on the other side of the link so that the return can be faster?

```
SELECT
    [Date] = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-@DaysBack,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    ,NOTES = N.RPMID
    ,TimeTaken = DATEDIFF("SECOND",SN.PickedUpDate,SN.ProcessedDate)
    ,PictureSize = SUM(CAST(DATALENGTH(SI.[Image])AS BIGINT))
    ,RecordsAdded = CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT)
FROM
    DBServer1.DB1.dbo.Notes AS N WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN DBServer1.DB1.dbo.NoteDistribution AS ND WITH (NOLOCK) ON N.Notes=ND.Notes
    INNER JOIN dbo.Submission_Notes AS SN WITH (NOLOCK) ON SN.RetailPlanGuid=N.RPMID
    LEFT JOIN DBServer1.DB1.dbo.SavedImage SI WITH (NOLOCK) ON SI.Notes=N.Notes
WHERE
    1=1
    AND N.RecordStampWhenAdd > CAST(GETDATE()-@DaysBack AS DATE)
    AND N.RecordStampWhenAdd < CAST(GETDATE()-@DaysBack+1 AS DATE)
    AND DATEDIFF("SECOND",SN.PickedUpDate,SN.ProcessedDate) > 0
GROUP BY
    N.RPMID
    ,DATEDIFF("SECOND",SN.PickedUpDate,SN.ProcessedDate)
```

The part in question is the picturesize that is returned. I want the calculations in there to be done on the server where the data is stored and just have the number return to me. Any help on this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What does "from what I can see" mean? How are you measuring this? I can't imagine any reason it would have to bring across the whole column to calculate the length. If you are looking at reads, it will certainly have to scan the whole table (or the whole index, if somehow you have a skinnier index that still covers your image column).

Comment: This portion was taking 97% of the cost in the Query Execution Plan. I figured that was probably due to the whole image going over the wire but maybe not. Thanks

Comment: 97% of the **estimated** cost on the plan diagram? What was the actual operator, the table/CI scan on `dbo.SavedImage`? That does not mean it was sending all the data over the wire. The execution plan show pre-execution estimated costs, and those have to do with CPU and I/O (of accessing the table/index), not network transfer at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure exactly how you have determined that all of the data is going across the wire (or why that should be the case) but you could always have a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SavedImage ADD PictureSize 
  AS CAST(DATALENGTH([Image]) AS BIGINT);
```

Or just add a column and calculate that yourself whenever you insert/update a row, either by forcing inserts/updates through a stored procedure, or using a trigger.

And persist and/or index that as necessary, and then just use `SUM(PictureSize)` in the query.

Of course the big impact is still going to be on the fact that you have to scan the entire table or index in order to generate the aggregate.

This method could also be used to maintain the total size of all columns in some other table, but I'm largely against materializing redundant data unless there is a demonstrated advantage to doing so.

In any case, I really don't think this query is slow because it is moving the whole varbinary data over the wire and then calculating the length at the wrong end; if you have evidence to suggest that is the case, please update the question and we'll try to address it.

Comment: Or just don't join across lined servers. Pull the data into temp tables and then doing joins also helps massively with performance especially if the network link is slow.

Answer (score 3):

Can you just make a `ImageSize` [persisted computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) in the source database?  That would calculate the size for you on insert and allow you to just request that data.

Comment: I don't own either database so as far as being able to add columns that would be a decision that would have to pull in a large number of resources. I'm hoping there is an easier way.